# pthread_equal() alternative for powerpc cross compiler?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, powerpc

I'm working on a program that reads the CAN datastream on a vehicle. The program will be used on an STW TC3g with an embedded linux.

I need to compile my code with a cross compiler based on the powerpc.
For multithreading I wrote a little example program to test some functions.

Here is the code:

```
pthread_t tid[2];
void* thread_pollCan();

int main() {

    while(1) {
        pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, &thread_pollCan, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, &thread_pollCan, NULL);
        printf("main:\tpid0:%ld\n", tid[0]);
        printf("main:\tpid1:%ld\n", tid[1]);
        pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
        puts("main:\tThreads terminated");
        sleep(3);
        puts("main:\tLoop end");
    }   

    return 0;
};

void* thread_pollCan(void* arg) {
        int  i;  

    // Should thread tid[0] do...
    if(pthread_equal(pthread_self(),tid[0])) {
        printf("tid[0]: %ld\t thread_self: %ld\n",tid[0],pthread_self());
        for(i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            printf("In loop %d\n",i);
        }   
    }   
    // Should thread tid[1] do...
    if(pthread_equal(pthread_self(),tid[1])) {
        printf("tid[1]: %ld\t thread_self: %ld\n",tid[1],pthread_self());
        for(i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            printf("In loop %d\n",i);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)pthread_self());
}
```

This program runs fine on my developing ubuntu pc if I compile it with gcc:

```
  gcc -Wall -pthread Multithreading.c -o Multithreading
```

Program output:

```
    main:   pid0:140207930042112
    main:   pid1:140207921649408
    tid[0]: 140207930042112  thread_self: 140207930042112
    In loop 0
    In loop 1
    In loop 2
    In loop 3
    In loop 4
    In loop 5
    In loop 6
    In loop 7
    In loop 8
    In loop 9
    In loop 10
    tid[1]: 140207921649408  thread_self: 140207921649408
    In loop 0
    In loop 1
    In loop 2
    In loop 3
    In loop 4
    In loop 5
    In loop 6
    In loop 7
    In loop 8
    In loop 9
    In loop 10
    main:   Threads terminated
    main:   Loop end
```

But if I compile it for my vehicle computer with the following:

```
powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc-gcc -O2 -Wall -pthread  Multithreading.c -o Multithreading -lm
```

Its program output is this:

```
main:   pid0:1026
main:   pid1:2051
main:   Threads terminated
main:   Loop end
```

The problem is, that the `pthread_equal()` function never match with the thread id wrote in the `tid[]`-array.

**So my question is, if there are any other methods to find the correct thread id.**

Comment: Can you display the thread id (`pthread_self()`) and `tid` array at the beginning of `thread_pollCan()`?

Comment: Thanks.
The return value from `pthread_create()` is with both compilers `0`.
So thats not the problem but when I display the `tid` and `pthread_self()` its get interesting.
With standard gcc-compiler I get the right tid and pthread_self() return.
With the cross compiler i get this:
`tid[0]:0 /  thread_self: 1026
tid[1]:0 /  thread_self: 1026
tid[0]:1026 /  thread_self: 2051
tid[1]:0 /  thread_self: 2051`

It seems that the current thread id is not saved in `tid[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're trying to read `tid[]` that does not have the time to get updated. You should add some `mutex` function calls to synchronize all:

```
// mutex for synchronization
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// pthread ids
pthread_t tid[2];

// thread function
void* thread_pollCan();

int main() {
    while(1) {
        // lock the mutex: thread will wait for it to be unlocked
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, &thread_pollCan, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, &thread_pollCan, NULL);
        printf("main:\tpid0:%ld\n", tid[0]);
        printf("main:\tpid1:%ld\n", tid[1]);

        // unlock the mutex: threads can run
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
        puts("main:\tThreads terminated");
        sleep(3);
        puts("main:\tLoop end");
    }   

    return 0;
};

void* thread_pollCan(void* arg) {

    // wait for mutex to be unlocked before working
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // immediatly release the mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    // do stuff
    if (thread_equal(tid[0], pthread_self())
    {  /*...*/ }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what "data" you are referring to. There are `pthread_join()` calls within the loop. So, only 2 threads ever run at the same time (apart from main) and they each record separate IDs.

Comment: By data, I mean `tid[...]`: I don't know if `pthread_create` is supposed to run the created thread after it has stored the new thread id in `tid`

Comment: Thanks your're great, that worked perfectly!
I only had to make a little correction in `thread_pollCan()`:
`pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
// do stuff ...`